# ORDER BY clause won't work in table created with SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I'm fairly new to SQL and have been learning by trial and error but I have walked into a wall with this issue. I hope someone could give me an advice.

1) Check if table already exist in database, if it does drops it [works]

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'PWC_L6_Daily',N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE PWC_L6_Daily
```

2) Create table with SELECT INTO statement from original table in same database, ORDER BY clause in this statement works without issues DESC or ASC [works]

```
SELECT Time_Stamp,Plate_Number,OP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference AS Sample_Tgt_Wgt_Difference,Plate_Weight_Target,Plate_Geometry,OP_NOP_Wgt_Difference
INTO PWC_L6_Daily
FROM PWC_L6 
WHERE ((Time_Stamp BETWEEN '05/09/2014 07:00:00' And '05/10/2014 06:59:59') AND (OP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference BETWEEN -6 And 6) AND (NOP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference BETWEEN -6 And 6) AND (Plate_Number <> 0) AND (Plate_Geometry <> 'Error'))
UNION ALL
SELECT Time_Stamp,Plate_Number,NOP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference AS Sample_Tgt_Wgt_Difference,Plate_Weight_Target,Plate_Geometry,OP_NOP_Wgt_Difference
FROM PWC_L6
WHERE ((Time_Stamp BETWEEN '05/09/2014 07:00:00' And '05/10/2014 06:59:59') AND (OP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference BETWEEN -6 And 6) AND (NOP_Tgt_Wgt_Difference BETWEEN -6 And 6) AND (Plate_Number <> 0) AND (Plate_Geometry <> 'Error'))
ORDER BY Time_Stamp ASC
```

3) Check if table already exist in database, if it does drops it [works]

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'PWC_L6_Report',N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE PWC_L6_Report
```

4) Create table with SELECT INTO statement from table previously created with SELECT INTO statement in same database, GROUP BY clause will work but it will give a random order, ORDER BY clause will do nothing. [does not ORDER BY]

```
SELECT MAX(Time_Stamp) AS Last_Produced,Plate_Number,COUNT(Plate_Number) AS Sample_Count,AVG(Sample_Tgt_Wgt_Difference) AS Avg_StT_Wgt_Difference,AVG(OP_NOP_Wgt_Difference) AS Avg_StS_Wgt_Difference,STDEV(Sample_Tgt_Wgt_Difference) AS Std_Dev_StT_Wgt_Difference
INTO PWC_L6_Report
FROM PWC_L6_Daily
GROUP BY Plate_Number
ORDER BY Last_Produced DESC
```

5) I did the following for troubleshooting and found the first ORDER BY clause (in 2nd step) affects the PWC_L6_Report table if I change to ASC or DESC but the second ORDER BY clause in this SELECT INTO statement won't have any effect at all. [Temporary statement]

```
SELECT Time_Stamp
INTO PWC_L6_Report
FROM PWC_L6_Daily
ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: You've failed to actually ask a question. But at a guess, you're under the misapprehension that tables are in some way ordered. They're not. They're unordered sets and any time you want something in a particular order, you have to explicitly request it.

Comment: @MarcB What's the "mysql native format" got to do with a question tagged sql-server-2012?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: sigh...mybad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you tell if data is in the order you want?  The statement:

```
select *
from table t
```

Returns the data *as an unordered* result set.  The only way you can impose an ordering is with `order by`.  You do *not* get data in insert order in SQL Server.  This is ANSI-compliant behavior and consistent with how almost all databases work.  If you want results in a particular order, then use `order by`.

`order by` can be used for an `insert` with good reason.  If you do:

```
insert into t2(col1 . . .)
    select col1 . . . )
    from t
    order by col1;
```

Then an *identity* column will be incremented in the proper order.  (This is a nice feature, but probably slows down the insert.)  You can get a similar effect using `row_number()` in your query:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by Time_Stamp desc) as id, Time_Stamp
INTO PWC_L6_Report
FROM PWC_L6_Daily;
```

Now you can `order by id` instead of `time_stamp`, if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Order by is only for presenting purpose. When used to insert data, it takes no effect. THINK TABLE AS SET.

Comment: Not true actually ... order by can take affect into the `select part`

Comment: Agree with both of you. It also take effects when used with TOP. Given the context, I don't think IDENTITY or TOP is used here.

Answer (score 0):

The difference I see is that in step 2, the variable you are using in the order by statement (Time_Stamp) is an existing column of the table. While in step 4 the variable you are using (Last_Produced) is not an existing column in the table - you are still in the process of creating that column.

In query 4, if you use order by max(Time_Stamp), then that should work I think.

Also, I have noticed that using variable name in order by while it is still being created, works if you are using 'proc sql and create table query' in a SAS environment. It could be something to do with the way SAS/SQL processes/saves data.